# Couldn't make precompiled header work with arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: c, gcc, arm, precompiled-headers

I'm using below gcc tool chain.
gcc version 5.4.1 20160919 (release) [ARM/embedded-5-branch revision 240496] (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors)

I could create .h.gch file but could not get .h.gch used while buidling .c files. I used -H and -Winvalid-pch options to check the reasons but compiler didn't give any information. Just like .h.gch doesn't exist and always search .h file.

Comment: How are you adding the file into your compilation process?

Comment: Hi Felipe, I'm using the dependency as below:
$(DependentObjs):%.o:%.c $(GCPHeader)
DependentObjs is a list of C files which include the header file. GCPHeader is the .h.gch file.

Comment: The problem is that precompiled header must be the first header file being included by C source code, including the header files listed in C source code and header files provided by gcc command line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that precompiled header must be the first header file being included by C source code, including the header files listed in C source code and header files provided by gcc command line.